# UrlValidator Symfony "the options "" do not exist"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to use symfony2 UrlValidator to validate an url parameters in a Service that I created. I tried this :

```
    $urlToValidate = 'http://www.google.ch/';       
    $validator = new UrlValidator();
    $validator->validate($urlToValidate, new Url(array('value' => $urlToValidate)));
```

But I get error :

> [Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\InvalidOptionsException] The
>   options "" do not exist in constraint
>   Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Url

Is there a way ?

**Edit 1 :**

I used :

```
    $validator = new UrlValidator();
    $validator->validate($url, new Url());
```

But I get :

> [Error] Call to a member function buildViolation() on null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
$url = 'http://malformedurl/';
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$violations = $validator->validate($url, new Url());

if (0 !== count($violations)) {
    // there is an error !
    foreach ($violations as $violation) {
        throw new Exception($violation->getMessage());
    }
}
```

As described here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html